# ReduxToolkit+Typescript: What to type the selector state type?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Lets say I am creating the following slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

interface ThoughtListDisplayOptions {
  shouldShowCreateDate: boolean
}

interface DisplayOptions {
  thoughtsList: ThoughtListDisplayOptions
}

interface OptionsState {
  display: DisplayOptions
}

const initialState:OptionsState = {
  display: {
    thoughtsList: {
      shouldShowCreateDate: true
    }
  }
};

const optionsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'options',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setThoughtListDisplayOptions: (state, action) => {
      state.display.thoughtsList = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

interface State {
  options: OptionsState
}

export const selectThoughtListDisplayOptions = (state: State) => state.options.display.thoughtsList;
```

And I want my selector:

```
export const selectThoughtListDisplayOptions = (state: State) => state.options.display.thoughtsList;
```

To be typed (meaning when I use it I want auto complete etc..). So in this case I added the state interface which only contains the slice that I am working on. (I have other redux slices in this app)

```
interface State {
  options: OptionsState
}
```

Is this the appropriate way to type the State? Or should there be some central State interface (or some other way to properly type the selector)?

Answer (score 1):

The selector State should be typed as `RootState` that you set up.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type

> ```
> import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
> const rootReducer = combineReducers({});
> export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
> ```

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-useselector-hook

> ```
> // TS infers type: (state: RootState) => boolean const selectIsOn =
> (state: RootState) => state.isOn
>
> // TS infers `isOn` is boolean const isOn = useSelector(selectIsOn)
> ```
>
> ```
> const isOn = useSelector( (state: RootState) => state.isOn)
> ```

You can also set up a typed useSelector function pretty easily:

```
import { useSelector, TypedUseSelectorHook } from "react-redux";

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```